# is saving money intrinsic or extrinsically motivated?

Tags: motivation

the 16 basic desires theory states that saving/collecting is intrinsically motivated. (Steven Reiss)

but monetary incentives usually fall under extrinsic motivation.
if you spend less you have more money so its like earning more...

or does it depend what you are saving the money for?

im trying to classify the motivation of online-pirates.

Comment: "Saving money" in terms of "collecting money to save for later" versus "saving money" in terms of "getting something for free/reduced cost" are separate concepts.

Comment: @BryanKrause In terms of "not spending 15$ on a dvd movie" but rather pirating the movie for free. thats what i'm trying to understand how are the concepts different.
my example clearly applies to your second example, but might as well apply to the your first example. as the pirate would deliberately not spend the money so he can use it for other things later.